# 6- or more dimensional Arrays in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, n-dimensional

I was looking into multi-dimensional Arrays in Scala and came across some easy ways to create multi-dimensional Arrays. Namely:

`val my3DimensionalArray = Array.ofDim[Int](3,4,5) 
//array with dimensions 3 x 4 x 5`

Or even

`val myFilledArray = Array.fill[Int](3,4,5)(0)
//Array of same dimension filled with 0's`

However this only works for 1 - 5 dimensional Arrays:

`val my6DimensionalArray = Array.ofDim[Int](3,3,3,3,3,3) //Error`

So how do people usually deal with creating higher dimensinoal Arrays? Is this left to 3rd party libraries to implement, or are there other data structures that Scala encourages us to use instead of high dimensional Arrays?

Comment: What do you need a 6-dimensional array for? This is not something that people need regularly.

Comment: I didn't actually have a particular use-case in mind - I was just wondering for completeness, in case the issue comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want arbitrary numbers of dimensions, you typically use a single flat array with a second array that indexes by dimension to get to the element you want.  So, for instance,

```
class MultiArray(dims: Array[Int]) {
  private val array = new Array[Double](dims.product)
  private def arrayIndex(index: Array[Int]) = {
    var i = index.length - 1
    var k = index(i)
    var n = 1
    while (i > 0) {
      n *= dims(i)
      k += n * index(i-1)
      i -= 1
    }
    k
  }
  def apply(index: Array[Int]) = array(arrayIndex(index))
  def update(index: Array[Int], value: Double) {
    array(arrayIndex(index)) = value
  }
}
```

would be a start.  There are various mathematics libraries that do this sort of thing (<strike>IIRC Apache Commons Math does</strike> I can't quickly find a Java mathematics library that does, but [ImgLib2](http://fiji.sc/ImgLib2) uses similar techniques for image data (they do local chunking also)).  It's not really a generally useful thing to do, which is why you tend to find it in maths libraries.

Comment: I don't get your last sentence. I also find flat arrays very useful. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ziggystar - Packing into flat arrays is most useful when trying to do fast arbitrary-dimension mathematics.  For general non-mathematical algorithms, if you need multiple dimensions there's little reason not to have actual arrays of arrays.

Comment: Ok, got what you mean. I checked Commons Math and couldn't find a multi-dim array implementation, can you confirm?

Comment: @ziggystar - Hm, you're right.  I was thinking of C++ libraries, maybe?  None of the Java libraries I checked do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
// create array of 5-dim-array => 6 dim array
Array.tabulate(3)(_ => Array.ofDim[Int](3,3,3,3,3))
```

`Array.ofDim` implementation uses this this pattern. see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L216-234

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works again for small (6 or 7 or so) dimensions, but for say 30 dimensions, wouldn't this be unwieldy?
`Array.tabulate(3)(_ => Array.tabulate(3)(_ => Array.tabulate(3) => .....`

Comment: @JoshLemer Sounds like `@tailrec` is your friend

Comment: @Daenyth I actually was just playing around with making a toy recursive implementation, but not sure it's possible, since each recursive call returns a different type. For instance
`def highDimArray(n: Int*) = 
    if(n.length == 5) Array.ofDim[Int](n(0),n(1), ... , n(4) )
    else Array.tabulate(n.head)(_ => highDimArray(n.tail: _*))`

..doesn't seem work as at each level of recursion, a different type is returned (Array[Array[Int]]], Array[Array[Int]] or Array[Int] etc.), so there's no way to define the return type right?

Comment: You need a type that's self recursive like `Free` or maybe `List`

Comment: I think the need for 30-dimensional arrays is sufficiently rare that it really doesn't matter that it's unweildy. I can't think of a use-case that uses that many dimensions without basically being a bad emulation of a tree/graph.